# AngularJS. Create chart.js on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I'm trying to create a chart and then change it to another with different data when I click a button but can't seem to get it to work. I'm using hardcoded data, here's my controller's function's code:

```
    $scope.generateChart = function(chart){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            "type": "line",
            "data": {
                "labels": ['Name','Name','Name','Name','Name','Name','Name','Name','Name','Name'],
                "datasets": [{
                    "label": 'Label1',
                    "data": [30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30],
                    "fill": true,
                    "borderColor": "rgb(0,0, 192)",
                    "lineTension": 0.1
                }]
            },
            "options": {}
        });
    };
```

And here's my template:

**chart.html**

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<div id="buttons">
    <button 
        ng-repeat="(key,result) in results[0]" 
        ng-hide="key === 'email' || key === 'country'"
        ng-click="generateChart(key);">
        {{key}}
    </button>
</div>
```

**results.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body ng-app="jellybeans">

        <results></results>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- build:js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Create plunker for this example or provide results[0] data you've used in ng-repeat of button.